No connection to gradle server. Try restarting the server. The Gradle Client Was Unable to connect
VS Code Error notification : Screenshot 
i am trying to run my FYP that i have completed last month. i try updating plugins for flutter & also upgrading flutter in the system. I also created a new project and tried to run it on both VS Code & Android Studio.
i thought issue is with java.Gradle or JDK.
i can't find jdk on my system,
not at C:\Program Files\Java
not at C:\Users\Name.gradle\jdks
here's pubspec.yaml if you want to know about any version:
name: exploreexperthotel
description: "A new Flutter project."

publish_to: "none"

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=3.3.4 <4.0.0"


dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  firebase_core: ^3.0.0
  firebase_analytics: ^11.0.0
  firebase_auth: ^5.0.0
  sign_in_button: ^3.2.0
  image_picker: ^1.1.2
  cloud_firestore: ^5.0.0
  intl: ^0.19.0
  firebase_storage: ^12.0.0
  google_generative_ai: ^0.4.3
  flutter_markdown: ^0.7.2
  flutter_gemini: ^2.0.4
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.7.0
  syncfusion_flutter_charts: ^26.1.38
  flutter_arc_text: ^0.6.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


  flutter_lints: ^4.0.0


flutter:
  uses-material-design: true


  assets:
    - assets/images/

In Android Studio it gives this error:
    Launching lib\\main.dart on sdk gphone16k x86 64 in debug mode...
    Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
    ../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/syncfusion_flutter_charts-26.2.8/lib/src/charts/common/core_tooltip.dart:168:22: Error: The method 'markNeedsBuild' isn't defined for the class 'RenderConstrainedLayoutBuilder\<Constraints, RenderObject\>'.

- 'RenderConstrainedLayoutBuilder' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/layout_builder.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/layout_builder.dart').
- 'Constraints' is from 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/object.dart').
- 'RenderObject' is from 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/object.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'markNeedsBuild'.
  renderObject.markNeedsBuild();
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/syncfusion_flutter_charts-26.2.8/lib/src/charts/common/core_legend.dart:452:22: Error: The method 'markNeedsBuild' isn't defined for the class 'RenderConstrainedLayoutBuilder\<Constraints, RenderObject\>'.
- 'RenderConstrainedLayoutBuilder' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/layout_builder.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/layout_builder.dart').
- 'Constraints' is from 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/object.dart').
- 'RenderObject' is from 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/object.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'markNeedsBuild'.
  renderObject.markNeedsBuild();
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/syncfusion_flutter_charts-26.2.8/lib/src/charts/common/element_widget.dart:117:5: Error: The method 'markNeedsBuild' isn't defined for the class 'RenderChartElementLayoutBuilder\<T, D\>'.
- 'RenderChartElementLayoutBuilder' is from 'package:syncfusion_flutter_charts/src/charts/common/element_widget.dart' ('../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/syncfusion_flutter_charts-26.2.8/lib/src/charts/common/element_widget.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'markNeedsBuild'.
  markNeedsBuild();
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/syncfusion_flutter_charts-26.2.8/lib/src/charts/base.dart:3317:7: Error: The method 'markNeedsBuild' isn't defined for the class 'RenderLoadingIndicator'.
- 'RenderLoadingIndicator' is from 'package:syncfusion_flutter_charts/src/charts/base.dart' ('../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/syncfusion_flutter_charts-26.2.8/lib/src/charts/base.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'markNeedsBuild'.
  markNeedsBuild();
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/syncfusion_flutter_charts-26.2.8/lib/src/charts/cartesian_chart.dart:1367:22: Error: The method 'markNeedsBuild' isn't defined for the class 'RenderConstrainedLayoutBuilder\<Constraints, RenderObject\>'.
- 'RenderConstrainedLayoutBuilder' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/layout_builder.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/layout_builder.dart').
- 'Constraints' is from 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/object.dart').
- 'RenderObject' is from 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/object.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'markNeedsBuild'.
  renderObject.markNeedsBuild();
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  Target kernel_snapshot_program failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

any kind of help is appreciated.
thanks in advance.
